# how to use the mysql between operator?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table in whitch each row have a date variable. i want to get the rows in between 2 dates that i give in the query.
exmple query:

Bdate is a field (column) in my mysql table.

Comment: Search a tutorial or this site, this is just to basic....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Bdate FROM table WHERE Bdate BETWEEN '2001-01-01' and '2010-01-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE BDate < MaxDate AND BDate > MinDate
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE BDate BETWEEN MinDate AND MaxDate
```

Where `MaxDate` is the upper bound and `MinDate` is the lower bound.

Comment: BETWEEN is inclusive, so you'd want 'BDate <= MaxDate AND BDate >= MinDate'